# Using jQuery-ui autocomplete to get sorted data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

So I want to use jQuery-ui autocomplete plugin to just get the sorted data in json format so that I can create my own custom UI. Custom UI would be like the one in attached sample image. For this, I need that the plugin doesn't show its default list.

Thanks,
Gaurav[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In autocomplete, there is a function called  _renderItem .

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item) {
return $( "<li></li>" )
    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
},
```

So, you can replace that _renderItem with your own.

Comment: Seems legit.. will try it.